# What happens at the server when a request is made and client quits immediately?

Tags: php, http

I would like to know what would happen if I have a code like that in a php page doit.php:

```
$url="http://someServer.com/somepage.php";

$i=10;
while($i--){
getDataFromAnotherServer($url);
}
```

now, knowing that function **`getDataFromAnotherServer()`** can take up to a second or two... 
What would happen if a user is asking for that doit.php and immediately close the browser ?
Would the function still be called 9 times (the loop would reach i==0) or stop somewhere in the middle?
Thanks

Comment: Is it that difficult to just try?

Comment: Do you need it to continue? There's [ignore_user_abort()](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script will be aborted (unless there is no attempt to send data to the client during that time). To prevent the script from ending early due to client disconnect, use [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php).

More detailed info on PHP connection handling can be found here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php

Answer (score 0):

the script would abort. the getDataFromAnotherServer function may take a few seconds im guessing as you don't control the server. this could cause the maximum execution to be reached as well. just something to bare in mind. ignore_user_abort may give the desired result